# Unable to retrieve value from parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am still learning AngularJS and I'm having some issues with scopes in my implementation.

The following is my controller and directive definition:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])

.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.parentVariable = "Test";
}]);

.directive('myDirective', [function(){
  return {
    restrict:'AEC',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var child = scope.$eval(attrs.myDirective);
    }
  }
}]);
```

The following is my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myController"
  <div my-directive="parentVariable"></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to retrieve the value of parentValue, however when I run the code child is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a few typos, once you clean them, it all works. Also, if you want to use a variable in the DOM, you need to make it a scope property. See below:

```js
angular.module('myModule', [])

.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.parentVariable = "Test";
}])
.directive('myDirective', [function(){
  return {
    restrict:'AEC',
    template: '<p>{{child}}</p>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.child = scope.$eval(attrs.myDirective);
    }
  }
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="myController">
  <div my-directive="parentVariable"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am wondering if you could answer some follow up questions for me. Is the parent scope of the directive the controller? Now suppose I have another directive A that uses a template that contains my directive <my-directive>, would the parent scope of my-directive be the controller or the directive A ?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, you're right - the parent scope is always the closest parent, e.g. "the first above", so the directive A would be the parent of your original directive in your second question. Generally, you shouldn't worry about what's the parent (unless you use $scope.$parent for some reason), but just make sure you pass in the right stuff to the directives.